# how to calculate the PV,ip,PU according to the tomcat log

Tags: tomcat, web-analytics

how to calculate the PV,ip,PU according to the tomcat log?

I have export the tomcat log to db.

Something about the db structure can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024313/look-for-a-database-design-related-manner).

For the ip I can use:

```
select count(distinct ip)...
```

But how about the pv and pu?

I have no idea,please do me a favor if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT ip from tblName) AS IPs, 
    COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT uri from tblName) AS UniquePages, 
    COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT username from tblName) as UniqueVisitors from tblName;
```

should work for you

---

To limit what type of pages should be counted, add that to the sub-query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT ip from tblName) AS IPs, 
    COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT uri from tblName WHERE uri NOT LIKE '%.js' AND uri NOT LIKE '.css') AS UniquePages, 
    COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT username from tblName) as UniqueVisitors from tblName;
```

Comment: The PV just caculate the pages,that's to say xx.js xx.css should not be caculated.

Comment: This can be added to the appropriate sub-query as I show above.

Comment: @hguser - It is not clear to me what kind of details you are looking for.  I have written a full query statement above.  You need to replace `tblName` with the table name from your tomcat log but apart from that, the query will provide you with exactly the information you asked for.